# How to advance rows of a Pandas DataFrame to the next value?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

My Pandas DataFrame contains a column of unsorted dates as strings, structured as '20201029' and so fourth. For each cell, I would like to advance the date to the next available date. See the following:

```
import pandas as pd


df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'label' : ['asc', 'vas', 'fe3', 'aa2', 'g4s', 'zzs', '44s', '2ab'], 
                        'original date'  : ['20200701', '20200701', '20200704', '20200709', '20200710', '20200710', '20200712', '20200714']})

# dates variable for sake of clarity, currently unused
dates = df1['original date'].drop_duplicates()

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'label' : ['asc', 'vas', 'fe3', 'aa2', 'g4s', 'zzs', '44s', '2ab'], 
                        'original date'  : ['20200701', '20200701', '20200704', '20200709', '20200710', '20200710', '20200712', '20200714'], 
                        'new date' : ['20200704', '20200704', '20200709', '20200710', '20200712', '20200712', '20200714', '']})
```

As you can see, each original date is compared against the list of dates and is advanced to the next date. 20200701 becomes 20200704 because it is the next date in the series.

I have seen the custom frequency ranges in pandas' business days function. However, this solution does not seem ideal as my dates are unpredictable and erratic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map`:

```
df1['new date'] = df1['original date'].map(pd.Series(dates.values, 
                                                     dates.shift().values)
                                          )
```

Output:

```
  label original date  new date
0   asc      20200701  20200704
1   vas      20200701  20200704
2   fe3      20200704  20200709
3   aa2      20200709  20200710
4   g4s      20200710  20200712
5   zzs      20200710  20200712
6   44s      20200712  20200714
7   2ab      20200714       NaN
```